# Old versions of Firebase for Unity (Firebase SDK 4.5.0)

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project, I am using libraries that depend on Play Services 11.8.0 and they crash with 12.0.1.

The latest Firebase 4.5.1 requires Play Services 12.0.1.

And for some reason I can't find on Google's website older versions of SDKs.
Am I missing something really obvious or for some reason they are pushing the latest version that hard?

Where is an official location to get Firebase SDK 4.5.0?

Answer (score 50):

In case anyone needs it - here is a magic link - `https://dl.google.com/firebase/sdk/unity/firebase_unity_sdk_${version}.zip`

Answer (score 1):

To download individual packages instead of the whole SDK, go to:

https://developers.google.com/unity/packages

In the download URLs just replace the version number with your preferred SDK version.

One can look into the `Assets/Firebase/m2repository` directory to find the Firebase SDK version.